# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement I dont understand

Tags: php

```
" . str_replace("<","<",implode(file("p2.php"))) . "";
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($_POST["ct"]))
                {
                    $numArray = explode(",",$_POST["ct"]);
                    foreach($numArray as $value)
                    {
                        if($value != " ")
                        {
                            $value = chr(158 - $value);
                        }
                        echo $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Could someone help me out and tell me what is wrong with this string, i get "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement", i really cant figure it out.

Bassicly im trying to complete the last level (http://www.hackthis.co.uk/levels/p2.php). I think im on the right track but its frustrating when i cant see what the problem is.

Cheers

Comment: That's very strange Java code. Are you sure you didn't want to add the PHP tag?

Comment: @Codo I am also thinking the same. I go on to think , is it a java code at all ? I guess it is a php code and should asked with php tag. Perhaps user1571379 may not know that .

Comment: Please post the code that comes before this, so we have full context and syntactically complete code to look at.

Comment: as far as understand, it is a java code trying to generate some php code

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape double quotations  like `\"` and use proper formatting for string. (use concatenation or type all in one line)

P.S: I assume you are using java to generate some php code, looking at the tagging you have made